# Google Distance API arrival time

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, google-maps

Okay, so I have my distance matrix request responding as if I didn't pass it an arrival time.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=875+Centerville+Road+Rhode+Island&destinations=1+New+England+Tech+Blvd&key=AIzaSyAkoZCNoX406xz-mmv2_O9Hji7oAkcoN7g&transit_mode=bus&arrival_time=194976000&sensor=false

This is the response I get back even with the arrival time parameter specified...

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "1 New England Tech Boulevard, East Greenwich,   RI 02818, USA" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "875 Centerville Rd, Warwick, RI 02886, USA" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "5.0 km",
              "value" : 5048
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "8 mins",
              "value" : 488
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
], "status" : "OK"
}
```

I get the same response if the url I pass is as follows...
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=875+Centerville+Road+Rhode+Island&destinations=1+New+England+Tech+Blvd&key=AIzaSyAkoZCNoX406xz-mmv2_O9Hji7oAkcoN7g

I get the same result whether or not I pass the arrival time...

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "1 New England Tech Boulevard, East Greenwich,   RI 02818, USA" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "875 Centerville Rd, Warwick, RI 02886, USA" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "5.0 km",
              "value" : 5048
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "8 mins",
              "value" : 488
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
], "status" : "OK"
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I need the API to respond with what time I will need to leave, to arrive at a specified time that I pass it.
I've not found a working example and this part is crucial to my application. Thank you.

I have a working response for the departure time parameter...but doing the same with the arrival time doesn't work. Does this API not actually work for the arrival time?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=875+centerville+road+Rhode+Island&destinations=1+new+england+tech+blvd+rhode+island&key=AIzaSyAkoZCNoX406xz-mmv2_O9Hji7oAkcoN7g&transit_mode=bus&departure_time=1949794160

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "1 New England Tech Boulevard, East Greenwich, RI 02818, USA" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "875 Centerville Rd, Warwick, RI 02886, USA" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "5.0 km",
              "value" : 5048
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "8 mins",
              "value" : 488
           },
           "duration_in_traffic" : {
              "text" : "7 mins",
              "value" : 432
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: your arrival time is in june 1976...

Comment: I still get the same response for the value 1449950160 which is 2 hours from now, I believe.

Comment: I still don't have an answer or solution. Someone please help me.

Comment: your transit_mode is `bus`, but you don't specify `mode`, which defaults to driving. (also, duration in traffic suggests it is indeed driving). Now, the documentation is not entirely clear, but suggest that it is not possible (see the doc on `departure_time` and the difference between transit mode and driving mode) to use `arrival_time` in driving mode. (which would make some sense, as arrival time is not necessarily a continuous function of departure time, and therefore regression is not always possible)

Comment: I see. I think I have the tools I need to carry out my project now. Thank you!! I don't know how to mark your response as my answer.